# Querying a composite key in SQLAlchemy-ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, composite-key

### Background

I have a composite index defined on a SQLAlchemy object, say:

```
class Shirt(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'shirt'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = Column(String(32))   # e.g. small, medium large
    color = Column(String(32))  # e.g. blue, red, white

Index('color_size', Shirt.size, Shirt.color)
```

---

### Question

I'd now like to do a search for `small` and `red` shirts, taking advantage of the `color_size` composite index.

**How do I write this query?**

Would the use of `and_()` automatically take advantage of the index?
For example:

```
results = Shirt.query.filter( and_(Shirt.size=='small', Shirt.color=='red') ).all()
```

Comment: BTW background research: I tried looking this up on SO [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsqlalchemy%5D++%2Bcomposite+%2Bindex) and [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsqlalchemy%5D++%2Bcomposite+%2Borm+%2Bquery) and Googled [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sqlalchemy%20composite%20index%20query) but have not been able to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the index should be used.  SQLAlchemy isn't using the index though, it only defines the index.  It's up to the database to use it for a given query.

You can use [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to prove that the index is being used.  For example, PostgreSQL shows an `Index Scan`.

```
example => explain select id from shirt where color = 'red' and size = 'small';
                                    QUERY PLAN                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ix_shirt_size_color on shirt  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=4)
   Index Cond: (((size)::text = 'small'::text) AND ((color)::text = 'red'::text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model class is called `Shirt` with (size, color) is the composite primary key:

You can query either with:

```
import sqlalchemy
...
Example.query.get((size, color))
```

or

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
...
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost/db_name')
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
session.query(Example).get((size, color))
```

Comment: Ok for `primary keys` but what about `index` (like the one in the OP question)?